# Change 'Return to Shop' to return to previous page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, hook-woocommerce

I found the below code to add a 'Return to Shop' button, it works perfectly

```
add_action('woocommerce_cart_actions', function() {
  ?>
  <a class="button wc-backward" href="<?php echo esc_url( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_return_to_shop_redirect', wc_get_page_permalink( 'shop' ) ) ); ?>"> <?php _e( 'Return to shop', 'woocommerce' ) ?> </a>
  <?php
});
```

I wonder if there is a way to change it to return to the previous page - i.e. like hitting back on the browser to the previous viewed product?

And one step further, could the text be dynamic, saying "Return to [name of previous page]"

This might be challenging!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like this

> More about [parse_url](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php)

It depends on how your links are constructed

```php
function action_woocommerce_cart_actions(  ) {
    // Pass the URL it came from. Expl: https://www.example.com/shop/product-1/
    $previous = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];

    // Get last part from url. Expl: product-1
    $last_part = basename( parse_url( $previous, PHP_URL_PATH ) );

    ?>
    <a class="button wc-backward" href="<?php echo $previous ?>">
    <?php _e( 'Return to ' . $last_part, 'woocommerce' ) ?>
    </a>
    <?php
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_actions', 'action_woocommerce_cart_actions', 10, 0 );
```

Comment: Great! Thanks for that, it works pretty well but needs a couple of tweaks. It takes the slug name, including all the - in the name. It also adds an item to the cart when clicked. I wasnt expecting anything as good, or a reply as quick, as this though, thanks!